# How to make a TextField fill all the remaining width of a pane containing multiple nodes?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to make a chat-simulating JavaFX application for my assignment  (no web functionalities, just two text fields for input and two text areas for output). I need to have a “Send” button next to my text field. I cannot make the text field to fill up the width of my window without “squishing” the button at startup, similarly to how swing’s boxLayout does that?

I bound the field’s width to the parent pane’s width, subtracting the button’s width and the pane’sspacing and it works after I start resizing the window, but when the application first starts up, the button’s text is not fully visible.

```java
public void start(Stage stage_main) throws Exception {
        //Pane creation and nesting:
        HBox pane_main = new HBox();
        Scene scene_main = new Scene(pane_main, 480, 360);
        BorderPane pane_left_parent = new BorderPane();
        BorderPane pane_right_parent = new BorderPane();
        HBox pane_left_bottom = new HBox();
        HBox pane_right_bottom = new HBox();
        pane_main.getChildren().addAll(pane_left_parent, pane_right_parent); //Focusing only on the left pane for now for testing.
        pane_left_parent.setBottom(pane_left_bottom);

        //Contents creation and nesting:
        TextArea textA_left = new TextArea("Testing...");
        Button button_left = new Button("Send");
        TextField textF_left = new TextField("Test input...");
        textF_left.prefWidthProperty().bind(pane_left_bottom.widthProperty().subtract(button_left.widthProperty()).subtract(pane_left_bottom.spacingProperty()));

        //Placing contents in panes:
        pane_left_parent.setCenter(textA_left);
        pane_left_bottom.setSpacing(3);
        pane_left_bottom.getChildren().addAll(textF_left, button_left);

        //Finishing up:
        stage_main.setScene(scene_main);
        stage_main.show();
    }
```

Is there any way to have the button have it’s “best” size already at startup without manually setting any widths in pixels, just like in swing?

Comment: Don't bind the pref width to the parent. Try using `HBox.setHgrow(yourTextField, Priority.ALAWYS)`.

Comment: This is perfect @Slaw! I needed to additionally add a `myButton.setMinWidth(myButton.getWidth());` line after `myStage.show();` in order for the button to not shrink down when making the window narrow, but other than that this works like a charm! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind the `prefWidth` to the parent. If you want a child of an `HBox` to grow horizontally you can set an `hgrow` constraint on it:

```
HBox.setHgrow(theChild, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Then let the `HBox` handle sizing and positioning the child node. And as you noted, in order to stop the `Button` from shrinking as the `HBox` changes size you need to set its `minWidth`. However, you should use:

```
button.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

If you use `getWidth()` you might accidentally call it before the `Button` actually has a non-zero width. Plus, using `USE_PREF_SIZE` means the `minWidth` will stay up-to-date with the `prefWidth` (if you change it for whatever reason).

---

Some links:

- [`HBox#.setHgrow(Node,Priority)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#setHgrow(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.scene.layout.Priority))
- [`Priority`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Priority.html)
- [`Region#USE_PREF_SIZE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_PREF_SIZE)